# Socket.io TypeError: this.transport is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have added user side error logging on my site. Some times it logs this kind of error coming from socket.io code:

```
TypeError: this.transport is undefined
```

The error have only been seen from users with Firefox 15th version on Windows.

On server side I define my transports like this:

```
this.io.configure(function(){
    self.io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);
    self.io.set('log level', 0);
});
```

Socket.io version is 0.9.10.

Can you please tell me what could be the reasons for this error?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` method is used for setting configuration for a specific environment. You are not specifying an environment, so you can remove the `configure` callback function and simply do:

```
this.io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']);
this.io.set('log level', 0);
```

Comment: Well does that change anything regarding the "this.transport is undefined" issue? Thanks for the replay anyway.

Comment: Yes. Because you are passing a function where a string (name of environment) is expected. See the documentation at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO (Search the page for "io.configure")

Comment: It states that "When configure() is called without an environment flag it will run in every environment." "this.transport is undefined" error only happens for some of the clients not all the time. Also the same client can be connected via two tabs and the error happens only on one off them.